# Perl: Adding values to anonymous hash

Tags: perl, hash, initialization

There is something like this

```
my $labels = {
   1  => 'One',     2  => 'Two',
   3  => 'Three',   4  => 'Four',
   5  => 'Five',    6  => 'Six',
   7  => 'Seven',   8  => 'Eight',
   9  => 'Nine',    10 => 'Ten',
};
```

I want to generate the same thing in a "For-Loop" with variables.

```
    my $labels;
    my @dData = ( "One" , "Two", "dynamic Data", .. );
    my $index = @ddData;

            for(my $i = 0; $i < $index; $i++){
                            $labels{$i} = $dData[$i];

            }
```

But the result is always:

```
Use of uninitialized value $labels in concatenation (.) or string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main errors here

- Your array is called `dData`, not `ddData`. You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of every program. This simple measure would have picked up your mistake
- Your index `$i` starts from zero, but it seems that you want your hash keys to start at one
- To access a hash by reference you need to use the indirection operator

Fixing these problems gives

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $labels;
my @dData = ( "One" , "Two", "dynamic Data");
my $index = @dData;

for (my $i = 0; $i < $index; $i++) {
  $labels->{$i+1} = $dData[$i];
}

use Data::Dump;
dd $labels;
```

**output**

```
{ 1 => "One", 2 => "Two", 3 => "dynamic Data" }
```

It is also far better to enumerate the elements of a loop, rather than use a C-style `for` loop. This would have been better written as

```
$labels->{$_+1} = $dData[$_] for 0 .. $#dData;
```

Comment: I'm a beginner so i used what i know ;) Your example worked for me but on change: dd $labels; to print Dumper $hashref;

Comment: and the parent of all these errors is not having `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't compile with `use strict;` and should be giving you additional warnings (for example, you use `@dData` in one line and `@ddData` in the next). I would use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $hashref;
my @data = qw(One Two Three Four);

foreach my $i (0 .. $#data) {
    $hashref->{$i+1} = $data[$i];
}

print Dumper $hashref;
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = { 
          '4' => 'Four',
          '1' => 'One',
          '3' => 'Three',
          '2' => 'Two'
        };
```

Comment: But he is using `$i < $index` for the terminating condition of the loop. It's just a dreadful variable name.

Comment: @Borodin You're right, I diagnosed that one incorrectly.

Comment: the "ddData" Array was a mis typing. I will try your suggestions

Comment: @user3412635 You should never freehand type your code into a question; always copy and paste. Otherwise the people trying to help you may find problems that don't actually exist.